# What should be /etc/hosts entry so that it works fine for both localhost & IP address?

Tags: localhost, hostname, hosts, domain-server

Sample `etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1         localhost
127.0.0.1         DEVubuntu
192.xxx.xxx.xxx   DEVubuntu
```

This is not working for me. I am not able to run Zookeeper and I am sure it's related to the `etc/hosts` file.

What should be the **ideal mapping in `etc/hosts` file** like localhost, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, IP address, machine name?

Comment: It would be nice if you can add more in detail as to what sort of error it throws, to assist you further...

Comment: @AzkerM please find updated question. The error is more specific to HBase. If you want, I can add that.

Comment: I think you have to remove the line `127.0.0.1         DEVubuntu` in any case, you can assign multiple hostnames to a ip but just one ip to a hostname in `/etc/hosts`.